# Is there a single word for standing still over a long period of time?

Tags: adjectives

It’s called ‘sedentary’ if you spend a lot of time sitting down. E.g. an office job.
I was wondering if there’s an equivalent for standing all day.

Comment: Your phrase “standing all day” already conveys the sentiment well.

Comment: @JasonBassford _Sedentary_ DOES literally mean _sitting_ - from the Latin _sedere_, to sit.

Comment: Use statant figuratively!

Answer (score -1):

I actually think that *standing all day* might be the best way of describing the physical behaviour.

However, if that's ruled out, there are two ways that this can be interpreted—because there are two applicable senses of [*sedentary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sedentary):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *adjective*
> **2 a** : doing or requiring much sitting
> // a *sedentary* job
> **b** : not physically active
> // a *sedentary* lifestyle

One interpretation of the opposite is with respect to physical positioning.

Sitting is to being sedentary as standing is to being [**upright**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upright):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *adjective*
> **1 a** : PERPENDICULAR, VERTTICAL
> **b** : erect in carriage or posture
> **c** : having the main axis or a main part perpendicular
> // *upright* freezer

Since you specifically mention *standing* ***still***, this seems most likely to be what you have in mind.

---

However, the other interpretation involves an [**active**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/active) lifestyle versus a *sedentary* lifestyle:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *adjective*
> **1** : characterized by action rather than by contemplation or speculation
> // an *active* life
> **2** : producing or involving action or movement
> **4** : quick in physical movement : LIVELY
> **5** : marked by vigorous activity : BUSY
> // The stock market was *active*.
> **6** : requiring vigorous action or exertion
> // *active* sports

---

Last, when I think of *standing still all day* in relation to *sitting all day* (both at an office job), I actually think of people standing at vertical workstations:

[image: vertical workstation]

Even though they can be considered to be standing still most of the time, people who stand actually do move around more often than people who sit. While it's not as observable at any given moment, they are more *active* and less *sedentary* (in terms of action).

Answer (score -2):

According to the OED's historical thesaurus 'Stationary' *used* to mean 'standing' and may have been the appropriate equivalent term to sedentary, but that is now obsolete.

> stationary  1656
>
> Standing, as opposed to sitting. *Obsolete*.

Therefore, it seems probable that a short descriptive phrase such as you use in the question is the best alternative.